# Will moving documents from a folder to the parent library cause issues with version history?

Tags: 2010, version-history, libraries

I'm having to move 1000s of documents from a folder into the parent library, I'm wondering if this would cause any issues with version history, ownership of the documents or the modified by/date, check in /out?  I would be moving the documents via Windows Explorer (using SharePoint 2010).

Comment: If you use the Content & Site Structure feature to move the files, all of the metadata and versioning should remain intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this and there doesn't seem to be any adverse affects to the metadata, version history, check out / in or modified date/by. Moving documents from a folder to a parent library causes no issues as far as I can see

Comment: Good to know. So looks like you found your own answer :-)

Comment: Slight correction on my comments above. I have tested again, it won't allow documents that are checked out to someone else to be moved, it will only move documents check out to you!

Answer (score 2):

It should be fine as long as you cut & paste (move) instead of copy & paste (copy).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The answer is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are going lose all those metadata information that you are inquiring about :-(. Looks like you would need a 3rd party tool if keeping metadata info is important. Check following links for details. Hope this helps!

```
http://oh365eh.itgroove.net/2014/11/26/using-open-with-explorer-in-sharepoint/
http://www.smellslikesharepoint.com/2013/03/17/sharepoint-explorer-view-disaster/
```

Comment: Why would the metadata disappear if all I'm doing is moving the documents out of the folder and into the parent library?  I didn't think it would cause the metadata any issues only the versioning/modified date and by.

Comment: Good question. I've not tested this out myself but I thought I read somewhere. Why don't you have a quick test with a test library?